# How to search if the key value in an array exists in another array, using PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I need a help. I have two arrays. I need to check if the values in first array are present in second or not. The arrays are as:

```
$maindata=array(array('id'=>3),array('id'=>7),array('id'=>9));
$childata=array(array('id'=>7),array('id'=>11),array('id'=>3),array('id'=>123));
```

Here, I need to check if each value from first array is present inside second array or not. If yes, then should return `true` else `false` at each time.

Comment: say in first array there are 3 element from where 2 element exists in second array. In this scenario do you expect true of false?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go, you can use the `in_array()` for PHP.

```
$maindata=array( array('id'=>3),array('id'=>7),array('id'=>9) );
$childata=array( array('id'=>7),array('id'=>11),array('id'=>3),array('id'=>123) );

foreach( $maindata as $key => $value )
{
  if( in_array( $value, $childata ) )
  {
    echo true;
  }
  else
  {
    echo false;
  }
}
```

You could also remove the whole if else and replace with a single line.

```
echo ( in_array( $value, $childata ) ? true : false );
```

Reference - 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php
https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ternary-operator-in-php--cms-24010

Comment: @RazibAlMamun the true false was placed in after the question was answered, I have updated to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

To check if an array contains a value:

```
if (in_array($value, $array)) {
    // ... logic here
}
```

To check if an array contains a certain key:

```
if (array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
    // ... logic here
}
```

#### Resources

- [in_array - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)
- [array_key_exists() - PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php)

Comment: I need to check in beetween two array.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will return `true` only if all elements of main array exists in second array, `false` otherwise:

```
$maindata=array(array('id'=>3),array('id'=>7),array('id'=>9));
$childata=array(array('id'=>3),array('id'=>7),array('id'=>11),array('id'=>123));

$match = 0;
foreach( $maindata as $key => $value ) {
  if( in_array( $value, $childata ) ) {
    $match++;
  }
}
if($match == count($maindata)){
    // return true;
} else {
    // return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_intersect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php)

```
if(!empty(array_intersect($childata, $maindata)))
{
   //do something
}
```

or

```
$result  = count(array_intersect($childata, $maindata)) == count($childata);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

```
$first = array_column($maindata, 'id');
$second = array_column($childata, 'id');

//If intersect done, means column are common
if (count(array_intersect($first, $second)) > 0) {
  echo "Value present from maindata in childata array.";
}
else {
  echo "No values are common.";
}
```